# Common words detect in different fields jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, how would you determine if one element uses a word that was being used in another element? For example: if one field contains the value: fishbucket, and another field contains fishdome, how would you scan the two fields to get the common word, in this case being fish? Or even with numbers, say one field containing the value 12793 and another containing the value 93127, common number being 127. Would you need to make a list of common words and run it against the values of both fields? Or is there a way to determine the common word without running a per-determined list. I can't seem to find the starting point, so if anyone can give me a place to start, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for jquery. Simple javascript will do. I can only give you a function to find longest in common starting string.

```
function commonStart(array){
    var x = array.slice(0).sort(), 
    word1 = x[0],
    word2 = x[x.length-1], 
    i= 0;
    while(word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(i)) ++i;
    return word1.substring(0, i);
}
```

e.g.

```
var testArray = ['testone','testtwo','testthree'];
    commonStart(testArray);
```

will yield 'test'

The standard tool for doing this sort of thing in Bioinformatics is the [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) program. It is used to compare two fragments of molecules (like DNA or proteins) to find where they align with each other - basically where the two strings (sometimes multi GB in size) share common substrings.

Comment: What do you mean by longest in common?

Comment: 'user27' and 'user28' wont return 'us' or 'use', it will return 'user' instead hence `longest in common starting string`.

Answer (score 0):

First List out all the values in  your form.

```
var inputvalue = []; //array declaration

$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
inputvalue.push($(this).val());  //saves value in array
});
```

then loop through all the values to get you common string by [pattern matching](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-jquery-david-sawyer-mcfarland-2nd/chapter-14/finding-patterns-in-strings)
you need to define common string should of how many characters long.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be broken down to finding the longest common subsequence.

Here's a [javascript](http://forrst.com/posts/Longest_Common_Subsequence_in_JavaScript-mQB) implementation for finding LCS beween 2 words. What you'll need to do is push all words in an array and then call LCS for each 2 strings you want to compare. (If return length is >1, there is a common text in between them).

There are a few string matching algorithms (based on hashes), you may want to google them too. Use only if requirement is huge, for usual cases, LCS implementation should be sufficient.